# How to get results between dates from current and every year after?

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to select rows between two particular dates. Every year we need to get a list of data that was entered between two dates, one from year 2016 ***09-01*** and one for this year.***09-01***.  Now, I was wondering is it possible to automatize the whole process by adding some kind of query that recognizes this date **(*09-01*)** in the current year and that same date in the next year.

Here is it query that I'm using right now:

```
SELECT naziv_plan, 
       Concat(glasnik.opis, ' - ', broj_glasnik) AS glasnik, 
       status.opis                               AS status_plana 
FROM   ispu_plan 
       LEFT JOIN razina_plan 
              ON razina_plan.id = ispu_plan.id_razina_plan 
       LEFT JOIN glasnik 
              ON glasnik.id = ispu_plan.id_glasnik 
       LEFT JOIN status 
              ON status.id = ispu_plan.id_status 
WHERE  id_razina_plan NOT IN( '8', '7', '6', '5', '4' ) 
       AND datum_donosenja_plana BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2017-09-01'
```

Comment: Quick question. Slow answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for your effort :) Here, take your +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
datum_donosenja_plana(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

Try this instead of

`BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2017-09-01'`

Comment: Thank you fine gentleman,  I think you are on to something but unfortunately this `datum_donosenja_plana(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))` does not work and in this case I need this `2016-09-01` particular date